# which one performs better binary search or sequential search on unsorted data

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, search, binary-search

If given an unsorted array which among the following two scenarios would have lesser time complexity or would perform better

1. Binary Search - by sorting the array first and then using binary search algorithm
2. Sequential search - on unsorted array

So if given an unsorted array to search an element should we go for sorting it and then apply binary search or directly apply sequential search algorithm on unsorted array.

Comment: It depends on situration. If the query is asked only one, Sequential search should be better. If there will be many queries for one array, sorting is required only once and using Binary Search is better.

Comment: Looking at it from the different perspective: why do you use an array to search for stuff in the first place? Keeping you data in a hash table (`<unordered_set>`) would give you a constant access time (at the cost of insertions).

Comment: For small data sets, sequential search beats binary search, especially when the data is not sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both exist because both have their places where they are useful.

If you will search only once, sequential search is fastest.  But if you do many queries, then binary search is faster.  Given that sorting is `O(n log(n))`, binary search becomes the same number of operations if you have to do `O(log(n))` searches.

BUT, operations are not created equal.  In particular binary search requires yes/no questions that are hard for branch prediction.  As a result, if you're searching a list of under 100 integers, a binary search is likely to be slower than a sequential search because the binary search has multiple pipeline stalls (each mispredicted binary choice) while sequential search only has one (when you find the element you're looking for).

So if you're doing many lookups, and you either have a lot of data or complex data (eg strings), binary search is better.